# Type of a singularity of a composition

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity-theory

Let $U\subset\mathbb{C}$ be open and $f:U\setminus\{z_0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ holomorphic with a pole of order $k$ in $z_0$. Further let $G\subset\mathbb{C}$ be a domain and $\varphi:G\rightarrow\mathbb{U}$ holomorphic and not constant with $\varphi(w_0)=z_0$.

What can you say about the type of the singularity at $w_0$ of $f\circ \varphi$?

The requorements on $\varphi$ imply that $\varphi$ is a open map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note the condition that $\phi$ is nonconstant is necessary so that $f\circ \phi$ is defined in some neighborhood of $w_0$ (since by analyticity there is a neighborhood in which $\phi(w)=z_0$ only for $w=w_0$), so that we're speaking of an isolated singularity.

The composition $f \circ \phi$ has a pole at $w_0$ if and only if $\lim_{w \to w_0} |(f \circ \phi)(w)| =\infty$. By continuity $\lim_{w \to w_0} \phi(w) = z_0$, and since $f$ has a pole at $z_0$ $\lim_{w \to w_0} |(f \circ \phi)(w)| = \lim_{z \to z_0} |f(z)| = \infty$, and thus $\lim_{w \to w_0} |(f \circ \phi)(w)| $ is indeed $\infty$ and $f \circ \phi$ has a pole at $w_0$.

Note we can't describe the order of the pole without knowing more about $\phi$: for example we can take $f(z)= 1/z^k$ and $\phi(z)=z^n$ to get a pole of order $kn$.

Comment: Perhaps something can be said about how the multiplicity of the resulting pole relates to that of the previous one? The general case certainly needs more attention but it looks interesting in its own right.

Comment: Can you tell me where you have used the "not constant"?

Comment: See my edit for the "not constant" comment; essentially so that $f\circ \phi$ isn't undefined everywhere in a neighborhood.